# Java Socket - ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, sockets, while-loop

Im calling ObjectInputStream all the time in while loop with statement true:

```
while(true){

            //send data

        }
```

but at moment when closing Socket, ObjectInputStream and rest i got multiple Exception Socket closed (actualy because i close it).

The question: what statement can i put in while loop to check ObjectInputStream is not closed?

Edit: Socket.isConnected() dont give good result

whole method

```
private void dataTransfer(){
    try {
        while(!con.isClosed()){
                String message = (String) input.readObject();
                ChatWindow.getMessage(message);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a bit more code so we can see what you are doing with the socket, inputstream, etc

Comment: Im closing sockets, input, output at JFrame windowClosing, but this while loop is still executing one time. is there any posibility to dont get that exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably multithreading asynchronization.

While the `while` runs outside the EDT, `windowClosing()` runs inside. Therefore it may check the `isClosed()` before `windowClosing()` was actually called, and execute the loop code after that.

As in similar cases, the best way is to use synchronization, but it's not the best idea in the EDT. Use a new thread in the `windowClosing()` method that closes the stream and synchronize that.

Comment: once we call input.readObject() it is waiting all the time to get the actual input, yes? so it is actualy imposible to dont get the Exception because even if Socket is closed we still waiting to get input and then crashing... am i wrong?